# C++ GetProcAddress not working

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

I have following code:

```
typedef int (WINAPI* fnEngineStart)();


int __stdcall EngineStart()
{
BOOL FreeResult = 0, RunTimeLinkSuccess = 0; //variables for later use
HMODULE LibraryHandle = 0; //Here the handle to API module/dll will be stored.
fnEngineStart fn = 0;

LibraryHandle = AfxLoadLibrary(L"FlowEngine.dll"); //get the handle of our API module
//so it will now be loaded.
if (LibraryHandle != NULL) //if the library loading was successfull..
{
    fn = (fnEngineStart)GetProcAddress(LibraryHandle,
        "fnEngineStart");
    if (RunTimeLinkSuccess = (fn != NULL)) //if operation was successful...
    {
        int ReturnValue = fn(); //call messageboxa function
        //from user32.dll
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Error", 0, 0);
    }
    FreeResult = FreeLibrary(LibraryHandle);
    //from this process...
    return FreeResult; //routine was successful
}
return EXIT_FAILURE; //else, it failed
}
```

This code works perfectly for example user32.dll and MessageBoxA but not my own dll...

```
int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall fnEngineStart()
{
   MessageBox(0, L"Succes!", 0, 0);
   return 0;
}
```

How do I make this to work for my own dll as well?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: GetProcAddress sets a value for GetLastError ...

Comment: And that error code will be 127. Because the function name is decorated. Potentially with C++ mangling, but certainly stdcall decoration. Either use a .def file, or, better, let the name be mangled and import it using its mangled name.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are dealing with is [Name Mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Use `extern "C"` so the compiler doesn't mangle the name. Example:

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall fnEngineStart()
{
   MessageBox(0, L"Succes!", 0, 0);
   return 0;
}
```

Note: `__stdcall` functions are name-decorated with a leading underscore, followed by an @, and then the number (in bytes) of arguments passed on the stack. This number will always be a multiple of 4, on a 32-bit aligned machine. [Source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions#STDCALL)

If your compiler supports it, you can do this in your dll and everything should work the way you have it now.

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall fnEngineStart()
{
   #pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:" __FUNCTION__ "=" __FUNCDNAME__)
   MessageBox(0, L"Succes!", 0, 0);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's more to it than that. The function will be exported decorated as `_fnEngineStart@0`. You'd need to use a .def file or switch to `cdecl` to avoid that decoration. Or just import the function with its correct name.